# Approve multiple releases out of order from a single release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a situation where I will queue 3 Releases from the the same release definition. These releases have approval gates and all halt at that point. My problem is that i can only approve them in order (i.e. release 1 then 2 then 3).

Is it possible to approve these in any order?

*For background: Each release is created with a variable which determines which server the deploy goes to so the order doesn't matter.*

Comment: Do you mean the same release with a few environments, each environment have approval and do you want to approve the environments without an order?

Comment: No each release only goes to 1 environment, and that environment comes from the variable. There is only one approval step in the release

Comment: Ok, I can approve which release I want, can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @CeejeeB, If I understand you correct, are you change the Deployment queue settings and change the Maximum number of parallel deployments to 2 and above?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT this is what I needed. Thanks if you post this as an answer i will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to approve these in any order?

Yes, you could lift the default limitation by select the option **Unlimited** on the tab Deployment queue settings:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior is indeed to only allow releases in sequence.
You can change this under the 'Pre-deployment conditions' of a given environment.
By changing the 'Number of parallel deployments' from specific to unlimited.

Or keep the specific, but change the amount to something else than the default '1' if that better fits your use case.

[image]